# Nested attributes with collection_select - Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view, attributes

When I press the submit button, it goes to my 'create' action and then saves the main object, but the foreign key is null as it has not been passed via post, here is my code:

Models:

```
class Ticket < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :system

  validates :title, presence: true, length: {minimum: 1, maximum: 60}

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :system
end

class System < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tickets
  validates :name, presence: true, length: {minimum: 1, maximum: 50}
end
```

Controller:

```
class TicketsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @system = System.actives
    @priority = Priority.actives
    @ticket = Ticket.new
    respond_to :js, :html
  end

  def create
    @ticket = Ticket.new(ticket_params)
    @ticket.save
    respond_with(@ticket)
  end

  def ticket_params
    params.require(:ticket).permit(:title, :active, systems_attributes: [:id,:name])
  end
end
```

View

```
<%= form_for @ticket, remote: true do |f| %>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :Título %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :title, class: 'form-control' %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :Sistema %><br>
    <%= f.fields_for :systems do |fs| %>
    <%= fs.collection_select :id,
      @system.order(:name),:id,:name, {include_blank: 'Selecione...'},
      {class: 'form-control', id: 'system_select'}%>
    <% end %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit "Abrir Chamado", class: "btn btn-info" %>
  </div>

<% end %>
```

So, it saves the ticket object with a title, but without a system_id, any helpful tip would be great here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few mistakes in your code.

Firstly,in your `new` action,you need to add this line `@ticket.build_system`

```
def new
  @system = System.actives
  @priority = Priority.actives
  @ticket = Ticket.new
  @ticket.build_system
  respond_to :js, :html
end
```

Your `ticket_params` method should be like this

```
def ticket_params
  params.require(:ticket).permit(:title, :active, system_id,system_attributes: [:id,:name])
end
```

Notice `system_id` and `system_attributes`.

And finally,you need to change this line `<%= f.fields_for :systems do |fs| %>` to `<%= f.fields_for :system do |fs| %>`

Comment: didn't work, when I write "f.fields_for :systems do |fs|" (plural) it saves the ticket with system_id  = nil, but when I write  "f.fields_for :system do |fs|" (singular) it doesn't even save the object.

Comment: Solved, my previous comment was happening for another reason. then thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't entirely understand your form, but in `ticket_params` it looks like you have the `:id` you want in the array value for `systems_attributes`. If that is indeed what you're trying to pass your new `Ticket`, then it needs to be passed differently within `Ticket.new`. The arguments/options hash you're passing to `Ticket.new` with `ticket_params` should be key-value pairs like so:

```
Ticket.new(title: "yourtitle", other: "whatever", system_id: "your_id")
```

I'd either change the output of  `ticket_params` so that it passes your system_id in this way, or manually pass it in (keying it out of the parameters) within your `create` action.